# Why isnt the windows 10 follina update dispatching?

Tags: windows-10, windows-defender, intune

For some reason, our devices have not received the windows 10 update that addresses the follina vulnerability since a month ago. This is making our exposure score look pretty bad...Why hasnt it been dispatched yet? I created an Attack Surface Rule in endpoint manager to block underlying office executions as recommended by microsoft, but it doesnt look like it affects/improves the score on defender.

Is the update still not rolled out? Should we be expecting something to change in the coming weeks?

[image: defender]

***checking KB5014699 update if installed:***

[image: update]

***Checking the registry, it doesnt look like there is a policy blocking windows updates:***

[image: TargetReleaseVersionInfo]

***AU:***

[image: AU]

***gpedit: windows update for business***

[image: Administrative Templates Windows components]

***UPDATE:*** Ive updated my PC to from 20H2 -> 21H2 feature update and now my device is no longer showing as an exposed device! Still, the question remains ***why didnt this update get dispatched automatically before***??

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137683/discussion-on-question-by-cataster-why-isnt-the-windows-10-follina-update-dispat).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out why the feature update 21H2 didnt roll out automatically!

An admin 2 years ago had set this restriction in MEM (endpoint manager) which blocked the update from automatically rolling out at the time.

We dont know why, but it could be because updates are usually "buggy" so the admin didnt want to deal with a bunch of reports at the time that the update  hinders user activity

[image: MEM]

Comment: @Ramhound found out why the update didnt roll out automatically!